# How to display image from MySQL in ReactJS using Express

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express

I have uploaded an image in the images folder of my Node server and the path is stored in the MYSQL database. I want to display the image in my ReactJS application. I am getting the error:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/images/abc.jpg 404 (Not Found)

```
const baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/data";
export default function Displaydata() {

const [userdata, setuserdata] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
axios.get(baseURL)
.then((response) => {
  setuserdata(response.data);
  console.log(response.data);
  });
 }, []);

 if (!userdata) return null;

 return (
  <>
  <h2>Data</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>S.No</th>
        <th>userid</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {userdata.map(({ userid, name,image },index) => {
          let sno=0;
        return (
          <tr key={userid}>
              <td>{index + 1}</td>
            <td>{userid}</td>
            <td>{name}</td>
            <td><img src={image} alt={image}/></td>
           
            </tr>
        );
      })}
     </tbody>
   </table>
  
  </>
 );
}
```

What can I try to fix this?

Comment: can you share the response please?

Comment: Please provide the exact error that you're getting. The link you have provided is on your own localhost.

Comment: @nima i am testing my app in the local machine. I stored the image path in database like http://127.0.0.1:8080/images/abc.jpg

Comment: Yes, but what is the exact response and error you're getting?

Comment: response: {userid: '1001', name: 'abc', image:'http://127.0.0.1:8080/images/abc.jpg'} error: http://127.0.0.1:8080/images/abc.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I would try and store the name only like 'abc.jpg' and add the rest of the link in the src and write it as you wrote the baseUrl 'http://localhost/images'